# ERROR: In file '.\docker-compose.yml', volume must be a mapping, not a string. - Docker with Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, docker, dockerfile

I have a developed site in Wordpress with a custom template. So i got only the wp-content folder since it contains all the template related files and plugins. With the Database dump. Finally defined the correct Wordpress image, MySQL versions in a "docker-compose.yml" like this.

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  db:
  image: mysql:5.6
  volumes:
    - db/user_portaldb.mysql.sql:/var/lib/mysql
  restart: always
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
    MYSQL_USER: wordpress
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress

  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:4.9.7
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - user_portal/wp-content:/var/www/html/wp-content
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
volumes:
  user_portal/wp-content
db:
  db/user_portaldb.mysql.sql
```

Once i executed this docker command,

```
docker-compose up -d
```

I'm getting this error:

ERROR: In file '.\docker-compose.yml', volume must be a mapping, not a string.

I have installed Docker in my Windows environment.

Comment: Please post code as formatted text, not pictures.

Comment: I posted the picture because it's difficult to put code indentation in the stackoverflow editor.

Comment: I can't copy and paste code from your picture to help you. And others cannot search on your question with a picture. Please post the text, and when you highlight the text and click the code brackets, the SO editor will maintain the indentation.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/596285

Comment: @BMitch : Done. Thanks for showing the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
- ./userportal/wp-content:/var/www/html/wp-content
```

for your volume. `docker-compose` and `docker stack deploy` understand relative paths for volume names with that syntax. Without the leading `./` it will interpret the string as a named volume. See the short syntax for volumes for more details: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#short-syntax-3

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I tried said method. But i'm getting this error - "Pulling db (mysql:5.6)...
ERROR: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)"

Comment: @CodeCanyon it appears you've resolved this issue and now have a new problem. That should be posted as a new question.

Comment: No this error came before as well. But i'm not sure the reason. Anyhow this error occurred before after i done a some fix.

Comment: @CodeCanyon The error in your question title and body of your question is about a volume syntax with a docker-compose.yml file. The new error is with network connectivity from the docker engine to a registry server. These need to be posted as separate questions on the site.

Comment: Thanks and posted as a new question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51472373/error-get-https-registry-1-docker-io-v2-net-http-request-canceled-while-wa

Comment: please give more context around your answer. Seeing this within the context of the whole file rather than a single one liner