# ERROR: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection-Docker with Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, docker, dockerfile

I have a developed site in Wordpress with a custom template. So i got only the wp-content folder since it contains all the template related files and plugins. With the Database dump. Finally defined the correct Wordpress image, MySQL versions in a "docker-compose.yml". There was an issue an i could able to fix that by posting it on this thread - [ERROR: In file '.\docker-compose.yml', volume must be a mapping, not a string. - Docker with Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51438374/error-in-file-docker-compose-yml-volume-must-be-a-mapping-not-a-string)

But now i'm getting this error when i executed following docker command.

```
docker-compose up -d
```

This is the error,

```
"ERROR: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)"
```

Comment: hi, may i know you found the solution for your question? mind to share your solution... i have the same issue wish to get your sharing.

Answer (score -1):

Could able to fix this issue by adding Google DNS to Netwrok settings in Docker. Exact value is:

```
8.8.8.8
```